# Remove string quotes from array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, coordinates

I'm trying to get rid of some characters in my array so I'm just left with the `x` and `y` coordinates, separated by a comma as follows:

```
[[316705.77017187304,790526.7469308273]
 [321731.20991025254,790958.3493565321]]
```

I have used `zip()` to create a `tuple` of the `x` and `y` values (as pairs from a list of strings), which I've then converted to an array using `numpy`. The array currently looks like this:

```
[['316705.77017187304,' '790526.7469308273,']
 ['321731.20991025254,' '790958.3493565321,']]
```

I need the output to be an array.

I'm pretty stumped about how to get rid of the single quotes and the second comma. I have read that `map()` can change string to numeric but I can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your required output is first one?

Comment: Yes it is. Just had a thought, do I need to convert the strings to numbers before adding them to the tuple? Thanks

Comment: I am not very sure check my answer below.. may be helpful for you else I will delete.

Comment: *`I have read that map() can change string to numeric`* not actually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [31.2. ast — Abstract Syntax Trees¶](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html)

```
import ast
xll =  [['321731.20991025254,' '790958.3493565321,'], ['321731.20991025254,' '790958.3493565321,']]
>>> [ast.literal_eval(xl[0]) for xl in xll]
[(321731.20991025254, 790958.3493565321), (321731.20991025254, 790958.3493565321)]
```

Above gives list of tuples for list of list, type following:

```
>>> [list(ast.literal_eval(xl[0])) for xl in xll]
[[321731.20991025254, 790958.3493565321], [321731.20991025254, 790958.3493565321]]
```

OLD:  I think this:

```
>>> sll
[['316705.770172', '790526.746931'], ['321731.20991', '790958.349357']]
>>> fll = [[float(i) for i in l] for l in sll]
>>> fll
[[316705.770172, 790526.746931], [321731.20991, 790958.349357]]
>>>
```

old Edit:

```
>>> xll =  [['321731.20991025254,' '790958.3493565321,'], ['321731.20991025254,' '790958.3493565321,']]
>>> [[float(s) for s in xl[0].split(',') if s.strip() != ''] for xl in xll]
[[321731.20991025254, 790958.3493565321], [321731.20991025254, 790958.3493565321]]
```

Comment: Once I removed the commas from the original strings, your "OLD" answer seems to have done the trick. Brilliant, thank you!

Comment: @user2727152 Try: `[[float(s) for s in xl[0].split(',') if s.strip() != ''] for xl in xll]` to remove `,` and convert into float in one step.