# Remove quotes from list items without making it a string

Tags: python, list

I have a list like:

```
Users = ['Protein("SAHDSJDSFJH"), {"id": "s1"}',
         'Protein("ACGTWZJSFNM"), {"id": "s2"}',
         'Protein("ABHZZEQTAAB"), {"id": "s3"}']
```

I want the same list as:

```
Users = [Protein("SAHDSJDSFJH"), {"id": "s1"},
         Protein("ACGTWZJSFNM"), {"id": "s2"},
         Protein("ABHZZEQTAAB"), {"id": "s3"}]
```

Without making the second list as a string, I just want the single quotes to be removed from the list items. Since, I am parsing it to a library in python to calculate a number iteratively using the ids. The function gives an error when encounters a quotes in the list items.

Comment: If you print these out you will not see the quotes, they are already strings. The quotes are simply to notate their type.

Comment: If you're concerned about the quotes being a part of the string, they aren't; they're just used to enclose whatever is already INSIDE the quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove string quotes from array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352016/remove-string-quotes-from-array-in-python)

Comment: How are you using the list, and why is it relevant whether its members are displayed with quotes (signifying string literals)? This looks to me like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Chris I have edited the question

Comment: @shalini How did you even get a list like that?

Comment: Erm, okay, now we've got a very different situation. Where did the string values originally come from? (It's usually best to fix these types of issues where they originate.) What is the function that "gives an error when [it] encounters quotes in the list items"? Please read [ask] for tips on asking effective questions.

Comment: @Chris Using a for loop, I appended the list items. 
after that, I am trying to compute a distance matrix, using
DistanceMatrix.from_iterable(users, metric= kmer_distance, key= 'id')

Comment: But where did the items themselves come from? How did the strings like `'Protein("SAHDSJDSFJH"), {"id": "s1"}'` get formed in the first place?

Comment: @Artyer I have appended the items in the list using a for loop

Comment: @Chris I used 
`users.append('Protein (" ' +dsspSeqList[i]+ ' ", {"id" : "s'  +str(i +1)+ ' "})  ')`

Comment: @shalini You should instead do `users.append(Protein(dsspSeqList[i]))` `users.append({"id": "s" + str(i + 1)})`

Comment: Thanks @Artyer Now, it gets no quotes and even makes it a list. But my code doesn't recognizes the key ='id' metadata. :( I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use below *list comprehension* using `map` with `eval(...)` as:

```
import ast

Users = ['Protein("SAHDSJDSFJH"), {"id": "s1"}',
         'Protein("ACGTWZJSFNM"), {"id": "s2"}',
         'Protein("ABHZZEQTAAB"), {"id": "s3"}']

new_list = [y for x in map(eval, Users) for y in x]
```

where `new_list` will hold the value:

```
[Protein("SAHDSJDSFJH"), {'id': 's1'}, 
 Protein("ACGTWZJSFNM"), {'id': 's2'}, 
 Protein("ABHZZEQTAAB"), {'id': 's3'}]
```

PS: Note that there should exists a class definition `Protein` in the scope whose `__init__` expects one string variable as an argument, and `__repr__` function to display the `Protein`'s object in the format you require . For example:

```
class Protein:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Protein("%s")' % self.x
```

**Note**: Usage of `eval` in Python code is not a good practice. You should not be using it for the live application, however it is fine to use it for home-work (if that's the case). Take a look at: [*Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) for the details.

**Edit:** Based on the comment by the OP. Instead of using:

```
users.append('Protein (" ' +dsspSeqList[i]+ ' ", {"id" : "s' +str(i +1)+ ' "}) ')
```

you should be using:

```
users.append(Protein(dsspSeqList[i], {"id" : "s{}".format(i +1)}))
```

This way you don't need a `eval` function. But *Note* part will still be applicable.

Comment: I don't believe `ast.literal_eval` will understand `Protein(…)` here.

Comment: @Chris : Oh yes. We should be using `eval` here. Updated the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Please note that `eval()` is not generally a safe function to use. If there is any way to fix the input values it would be preferable to this solution.

Comment: Yup that's true

Comment: Thank you. @MoinuddinQuadri This fixed my problem. YAAYY

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing like list with

```
print(Users)
```

try

```
print("Users = [%s]" % ", ".join(Users))
```

This formats the output so that it looks like you mentioned.

Comment: This makes it is a string... OP asked a meaningless question.

Comment: This make it a string. I want it to still be a list.

Comment: @shalini your question doesn't make sense if you're looking for it to be a list.  The quote marks just show what data type python thinks your list contains.  The only way you could remove the quote marks is if you were trying to display the contents of the list.